# Python: Select items from a 2D array based on indices of another 2D array

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to do a simple task, but can't figure out a quick solution.

I have two 2D arrays of the same size. One array is a mask array that simply contains either 0s or 1s; I want to retain values in another array wherever the mask array index is 1.

The mask array could look like:

```
mask    = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1]]
```

And say I have a second array of:

```
testarr  = [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]
```

I want to extract the values `[2,2,3,4]` from `testarr`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Those are not 2D arrays; they're ragged lists.

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if you got your solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you convert your `mask` to bools, you can use numpy to do this.  First convert your arrays to numpy arrays using `maskl = np.array(mask, dtype=bool)` and `estarray = np.array(estarray)`.  Then:

```
>>> estarr[mask]
array([2, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, BrenBarn.  This works wonders in my script!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `zip`.

```
for mask_list,val_list in zip(arr1, arr2):
    for m,v in zip(mask_list, val_list):
       if m:
           # put in results
```

Comment: This solution is likely to be way, way slower than using numpy, especially if the arrays are large.

Comment: But it is a solution, and not everyone has numpy. Also these are not arrays but lists...

Comment: Anyone who doesn't have numpy should get it anyway :-).

Comment: I prefer to use numpy whenever possible since my arrays are 100 x 100 (or larger) usually.  Thanks for your non-numpy solution, though, Skurmedel!

Answer (score 2):

You could flatten the lists with [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and then simply iterate over the zipped lists, e.g. like the following:

```
mask     = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1]]
testarr  = [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]

from itertools import chain, izip
print [x for m,x in izip(chain(*mask), chain(*testarr)) if m]
# output:
#  [2, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mask    = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1]]
testarr  = [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]
n = len(mask)
m = len(mask[0])
filtered = []
for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(m):
                if mask[i][j]:
                        filtered.append(testarr[i][j])
```

This is how I'd do it. maybe you can write this as a separate function, and pass in the two lists.

There might be more "elegant" ways, but I don' think there's more "efficient" ways to do it. Personally I like the readability.

Comment: This is how I was doing it initially, but actual arrays have several thousand elements, so the loop was bogging down the runtime.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't see how it could be done without doing n.m comparisons.

Btw, xrange should make it faster than range.

How was the speed of the solutions using numpy? If you do find a faster way to do it. Let us know.

Answer (score 0):

You might also check out the numpy.ma module. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html

```
import numpy as np
mask    = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1]],dtype=np.bool)
testarr  = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]])

ma = np.ma.array(testarr, mask=np.invert(mask))
print ma[~ma.mask]
```

output

```
[2 2 3 4]
```